# Automatically adding extra space to result and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, keypress

I am learning JavaScript.

I have created a `input` and a `button`. So whenever user type anything in the input it will show in the list item. It is working as expected but the automatic space and console error is bugging me.

Automatic space :- The first result has no space between `1` and `Rahul`. Whereas other result have space between them. The results are added in list item in two different events. 
1) On Enter key press
2) On click on `add new` button

[image: automatic space]

Console error

[image]

```js
    document.getElementById('user_input').focus();
    function onPress_ENTER()
    {
     var keyPressed = event.keyCode || event.which;
    
               //if ENTER is pressed
               if(keyPressed==13)
               {
                incre();
                keyPressed=null;
               }
               else
               {
                return false;
               }
           }
    
           var count = 0;
    
           onPress_ENTER();
           function incre(){
            
            
            count += 1;
            var text = document.createTextNode(count);
    
            var el = document.createElement("li");
     //get text from input box and create node
     var user_input = document.getElementById('user_input').value;
     var user_input_node = document.createTextNode(user_input);
     
     //create element node span and add user input inside span
     var user_el = document.createElement('span');
     user_el.appendChild(user_input_node);
    
     //id of list item element
     var id_el = document.getElementById('list_item');
    
     //append counter inside the li
     el.appendChild(text);
     el.appendChild(user_el);
    
     id_el.appendChild(el);
     document.getElementById('user_input').value = " ";
     document.getElementById('user_input').focus();
    
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="user_input" onkeypress="onPress_ENTER()">
<input type="button" onclick="incre()" value="add new">

<ul id="list_item">
 
</ul>
```

Comment: Standard `event` object is passed to the event handler only. Forget the  non-standard global event object implemented by IE and Chrome.

Comment: Even if I remove the `event` from `var keyPressed = keyCode || which;` it is same. No changed.

Comment: Nope, there's a big difference in the error messages, please read them carefully. As you  see, "Cannot  read property 'keyCode' __of__ undefined." vs. "'keyCode' is not defined."

Comment: Same error message.`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined` This message is same as the screenshot posted in my question.

Comment: Actually that is irrelevant, please add `event` to the argument list of the handler, that's all you need.

Comment: @Teemu its not working though. If I add `event` it will throw console error everytime I type anything

Comment: remove the function call to `onPress_ENTER();`    in the mdidle of the script that is there for no reason

Comment: I did it and it fixed the console error. Thank you very much. Also can you help me to find out why the space is added after 2nd result

Comment: change this line: `document.getElementById('user_input').value = " ";`  to  just being  `= ""` without a space in between the two quotes... the whole thing would be:   `document.getElementById('user_input').value = "";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is on how you organized your code.

You can call the function ***onPress_ENTER*** only at document ready.

For the event I suggest you to pass it directly in the inline call.

Instead of ***keyPressed=null;***  you can use preventDefault.

In order to reset the input field you can write:

```
// reset input
document.getElementById('user_input').value = "";
document.getElementById('user_input').focus();
```

but, when you need to add this to the list you can change this line:

```
 var user_input = document.getElementById('user_input').value;
```

to:

```
var user_input = " " + document.getElementById('user_input').value;
```

The example:

```js
// when document is ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('user_input').focus();
  onPress_ENTER(e); // this is useless.....
});


// global func and var
function onPress_ENTER(e) {
  var keyPressed = e.keyCode || e.which;

  //if ENTER is pressed
  if (keyPressed == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    incre();
  }
}

var count = 0;

function incre() {
  count += 1;
  var text = document.createTextNode(count);

  var el = document.createElement("li");
  //get text from input box and create node
  var user_input = " " + document.getElementById('user_input').value;
  var user_input_node = document.createTextNode(user_input);

  //create element node span and add user input inside span
  var user_el = document.createElement('span');
  user_el.appendChild(user_input_node);

  //id of list item element
  var id_el = document.getElementById('list_item');

  //append counter inside the li
  el.appendChild(text);
  el.appendChild(user_el);

  id_el.appendChild(el);

  // reset input
  document.getElementById('user_input').value = "";
  document.getElementById('user_input').focus();

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="user_input" onkeypress="onPress_ENTER(event)">
<input type="button" onclick="incre()" value="add new">

<ul id="list_item">

</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome. Due to ` document.getElementById('user_input').value = " ";` It was working for all the second and not the first. By adding it outside the function it worked for the first one as well. Thanks. It helped me to understand alot.

Comment: @Santosh I'm happy for you. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

here: `var count = 0; onPress_ENTER();` you call a function without event. You need to remove this call

look at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24ykzqx3/)

```
document.getElementById('user_input').focus();
function onPress_ENTER()
{
   var keyPressed = event.charCode || event.which;
//if ENTER is pressed
    if(keyPressed==13)
    {
        incre();
        keyPressed=null;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
var count = 0;
function incre(){
    count += 1;
    var text = document.createTextNode(count);

    var el = document.createElement("li");
    //get text from input box and create node
    var user_input = document.getElementById('user_input').value;
    var user_input_node = document.createTextNode(user_input);

    //create element node span and add user input inside span
    var user_el = document.createElement('span');
    user_el.appendChild(user_input_node);

    //id of list item element
    var id_el = document.getElementById('list_item');

    //append counter inside the li
    el.appendChild(text);
    el.appendChild(user_el);

    id_el.appendChild(el);
    document.getElementById('user_input').value = " ";
    document.getElementById('user_input').focus();
}
```

Comment: hmmm...  strange. I tested it and after replace keyCode to charCode error stopped to appear in console

Comment: I copied and paste your code and still says that `Cannot read property 'charCode' of undefined`  So does it mean its working in your case and not in my case ? Can you show me a fiddle ?

Comment: one moment. It seems I found a reason. here: `var count = 0;
onPress_ENTER();` you call a function without event

Comment: What event should be there any idea ? I tired using `onPress_ENTER(charCode);` and its same.

Comment: I've changed the answer.

Comment: Thanks That solve the error issue. Can you also help me why the space is getting added after 2nd result

Comment: here in the func incre(): `document.getElementById('user_input').value = " ";` you assign value of input a space. but you need to assign `""`. changed jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/24ykzqx3/